# LiipImagineBundle and 'filter not defined'

Tags: image, symfony, filter, resize, defined

I installed LiipImagineBundle.

config.yml:

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

AppKernel.php:

```
    $bundles = array(
        ...
        new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
    );
```

And when I want to use filter:

```
    <td><img src="{{ asset('images/zestawy/'~entity.zdjecie) | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" /></td>
```

I get this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Filter not defined: my_thumb")
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the route in your routing.yml?

```
_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine
```

Also make sure you have cleared your cache

```
php app/console cache:clear --env="dev"
php app/console cache:clear --env="prod"
```

Comment: Yes i did, like instruction said.

Comment: Try clearing your cache: 
php app/console cache:clear --env="dev" and php app/console cache:clear --env="prod"

Comment: I deleted cache/dev folder at the beginning. And nothing. :(

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/8xvVfM66) - my config.yml, [link](http://pastebin.com/KfzZusbT) - my routing.yml.

Comment: Your filterset/filter name is filterek not my_thumb

Comment: It's mistake because i was trying another names. Ofc problem exist also when names are the same.

Comment: I totally delete liip_imagine from config.yml and nothing changed, exception is that same.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. NetBeans is crazy and he stopped actualize files.